# Unable to recieve response from linkedin api company search

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am building a small C# client to connect to linkedin api. When I am trying to get my own profile from linkedin api (using OAuth2), I am getting correct response. But whenever I do a company search on industry, the api is not returning any data. This is a simple query that I am using for testing purpose -

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?facet=industry,54&format=json

Is this query correctly formed? Have tried many different Urls as shown below but none of them seems to work for me.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(facets,companies:(id,name,universal-name))?facet=industry,54&format=json

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?facets=industry&facet=industry,54&format=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out that the facet value of query has to be encoded here. I thought the ',' in 'industry,54' must be how linkedin might be parsing the facet value. Anyways, below works -

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?facet=industry%2C54&format=json

Comment: do you know how to specify multiple facets?